# Typescript value of 2nd item of array based on value of 1st item array

Tags: typescript

I have object of arrays, where each array is pair `[value, function]`, where `function` accepts `value` in parameter:

```
const items = {
    first: ['a', val => val.length], // val should be string
    second: [[1, 2], val => val.push(3)] // val should be number[]
}
```

Is there any way to set the type of function parameter (second array item) the same as the type of first array item? I created this, but it's not working (a type of function parameter is always unknown):

```
type Items = {
    [key: string]: any extends [infer Value, any] ? [Value, (val: Value) => any] : never
}

const items: Items = {
    first: ['a', val => val.length], // val should be string, but is unknown
    second: [[1, 2], val => val.push(3)] // val should by number[], but is unknown
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a bit safer alternative to hinosxz's answer ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsDOUC8UDeAoKuoG0BpALiiWACcBLAOwHMBdUuRAHgEMaQAaKAVxoBrGgHsA7jQB8WAL5ZQkWPASsAKrwCqktAXVQAFMFKqAlGm0aGWLAGMRNclCrKdazZP0A6b%20wp0kzMpuUFpmqNq%20-lAA9NFQAGbsNsAiFCAJNNZ2DsBOygFKiCjo2HgJVBTkpM6I%20gDk7HW8AG7sADbmUK1tnm0Q9MAAFia8sVBiqYJIOHhIENkAJtXK%20vgAjLwATAwt7Z3dnmB8SIP6AMwmIzFxExRT1mVDFUt5tRgyux3hXe29-XRDK5jCAUCipAx0EQiBYmGa4eIiPgUIbLN5QAAMpDWUA%20Py%202gORxO50u1ygILBFAhUJhsiAA)):

```
type Items = {
    [K: string]: Item<any, unknown>
}
type Item<T, U> = [T, (t: T) => U]

const item = <T, U>(...args: Item<T, U>) => args // factory fn

const items: Items = {
    first: item('a', val => val.length), // works
    second: item([1, 2], val => val.push(3)), // works

    third: item({}, val => val.length), // error (good)
    fourth: item({ 0: 1 }, val => val.push(3)) // error (good)
}
```

#### Notes:

With an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), all property values must have the same type. So you cannot use generic type parameters efficiently with it.

Also TS currently lacks a construct like [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) to express, that there is a relationship between property key and its value *per* property instead of all properties together.

To solve the issue, we can either type all properties explicitly as usual (omitted for simplicity) or choose a wider `Items` base type and check all properties individually with `Item` type and `item` factory function as shown above.

You better not use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) here, as its compiler checks are much more permissive than a regular assignment check. For example `third` and `fourth` [wouldn't trigger an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsA8AVAfFAvFA2igNFABQBuAhgDYBcUKAlFhmQHYgC6AUBwMYD2zAZ2BQAlvAQCsUAN4co8qADMRAJyE0c0gL6FyFRlD0A6ChGYBzYAAs2UMpLiIkQlSItp8chQIh9mAEw1pAAYaAEYdQ0oDYzAAVwErIgBmOlt7WHEkHGY4hAAjCBVCXIKitjQOLSA) with a type assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

```
type Item<T> = [T, (val: T) => any]


const items = {
    first: ['a', val => val.length] as Item<string>,
    second: [[1, 2], val => val.push(3)] as Item<number[]>
}
```

I used casting for this specific case because you have different types in the same object but I think you can rearrange your data structures to avoid casting.

See [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsA8AVAfFAvFA2igNFABQBuAhgDYBcUKAlFhmQHYgC6AUFwMYD2zAZ2BQAlvAQCsUAN4co8qADMRAJyE0cAcjKbC5Coyj6AdBQjMA5sAAWbKGUlxESISpGW0+OQoEQ+zABMNHABGQgAmNj1KQxMwAFcBayIAZjo7B1hxJGZ4hAAjCBUcNjQOAF8gA)